# Reducing noise and finding sampling rate

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, arduino-due, analog-sampling

I have Arduino Due R3 (84MHz) and I am trying to find the mean of value from AnalogRead. I have to set the sampling rate of 8000 samples/second with 4 channels. I tried using `for` loop for this purpose.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int i = 0;
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;
int highest=0;
int lowest=0;
float mean=0;



void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  analogWriteResolution(12);  // set the analog output resolution to 12 bit (4096 levels)
  analogReadResolution(12);   // set the analog input resolution to 12 bit
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  lcd.print("Hello");

}

void loop() 
{


  for(;;)
  {
    mean=0;
    for(i=0;i<8000;i++)
    {
       sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
     highest=max(highest,sensorValue);
     lowest=min(lowest,sensorValue);
     mean = mean + (highest-lowest);
    }
    mean = mean/8000;
    delay(10);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(mean);
  }
```

Will this set sampling rate to 8000 samples/sec ?

Also I was receiving  a lot of noise at *A0* which often led to the lowest value to be 0. In the image : The  red wave is a constant dc voltage of 2.7 V from power supply.
[image: The red wave is constant dc voltage of 2.7V]
How do I overcome this noise so that mean value is accurate and precise ?

Answer (score 2):

Just to as a complement to Majenko's answer (which I second), there are
a couple of flaws in your program that may be related to your problem:

- `lowest` is always zero, as it is initialized to 0 and cannot increase
- your computation of the mean is incorrect: the mean is the sum of the
  readings divided by their number
- you fail to reset `lowest` and `highest` between consecutive runs of
  8000 samples
- there is no point in putting all of `loop()` inside an infinite loop.

Assuming you really intend to print summary statistics on runs of
8000 samples, as your code suggests, I would write it like this:

```
const int SENSOR_PIN = A0;
const int SAMPLE_COUNT = 8000;
const uint32_t SAMPLE_PERIOD = 125;  // 125 us

void loop()
{
    long sum = 0;
    int lowest = INT_MAX, highest = 0;

    uint32_t lastTime = micros();
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_COUNT; i++) {

        // Wait until it's time.
        while (micros() - lastTime < SAMPLE_PERIOD) ;
        lastTime += SAMPLE_PERIOD;

        // Take and process the sample.
        int sensorValue = analogRead(SENSOR_PIN);
        sum += sensorValue;
        highest = max(highest, sensorValue);
        lowest = min(lowest, sensorValue);
    }
    float mean = (float) sum / SAMPLE_COUNT;
    Serial.print("mean: "); Serial.print(mean);
    Serial.print(", minimum: "); Serial.print(lowest);
    Serial.print(", maximum: "); Serial.println(highest);
    Serial.flush();
}
```

---

**Edit**: I changed the code in order to keep a roughly constant
sampling rate of 8000 samp/s. The main change is that, before
taking a reading, we wait until it's time to do so (until
`micros() - lastTime >= SAMPLE_PERIOD`).

Note that `lastTime` could be updated with `lastTime = micros()`, in
which case it would have hold the time we last took a sample. By
updating it with `lastTime += SAMPLE_PERIOD` it instead holds the time
we *shoud have taken* the last sample. This is the right choice for
enforcing a given *average* sampling rate.

**Running on an Uno**: I have no experience with the Due, but here are
some remarks that would apply to an Uno, or any other AVR-based Arduino:

- `analogRead()` takes about 110 µs, which means we cannot sample
  more than one channel, and we only have about 15 µs to process
  the sample. Here the processing is simple enough that the Arduino can
  do it in this limited time.
- There is some jitter in the sampling, because `micros()` has a limited
  resolution of 4 µs, because of the timer interrupt kicking in
  from time to time, and because the `while` loop takes a finite amount
  of time.

If I were to do something similar on an Uno, I would forgo
`analogRead()`, configure the ADC to be triggered by a timer, and set
the timer to trigger the DC every 125 µs. Not only would this get
rid of the jitter, it would also allow the CPU to do its job in parallel
with the ADC, instead of just sitting idle and waiting until the ADC is
done. This would allow for more complex per-sample processing.

**About the Due**: As I said, I have no experience with this board. It
has a more capable processor, but this tells you nothing about the speed
of its ADC. I would expect to face the same issues as with the Uno,
though maybe to a lesser degree. I *guess* it should be possible to
trigger the ADC from a timer, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Actually I wanted to calculate maximum and minimum per cycle and then calculate the mean of their difference for the given number of samples. I have updated my code also. Sorry for Incovenience.Also how do I set the sampling rate to around 8000 samples/sec if I'm using 4 channels with Arduino Due R3 (84 MHz) ?

Comment: @SamThornton: About the sampling rate, see the expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks !! Just there is 1 doubt ? Why can't I use mutiple channels ? What if use nested loop like `for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<8000;j++)
//take input and process
}`

Comment: @SamThornton: Yes, you can read one waveform on one channel, then another one on the other channel and so on. What you cannot do, at least with this scheme, is sample the four channels simultaneously at 8 kS/s. Unless your ADC is way faster than the ones on the AVRs.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks ! BTW Is there a way to do it simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this set sampling rate to 8000 samples/sec ?

No, that will make it perform a block of 8000 samples as fast as it can. There's absolutely nothing in there that has anything to do with time, so how can "seconds" be included in the description of it?

> How do I overcome this noise so that mean value is accurate and precise ?

That depends on where the noise is coming from. Maybe if you slowed down your sampling you wouldn't get the noise. Maybe if you made a better connection to whatever it is you're sampling you'd get less noise. Maybe if you added some external filtering you'd get less noise. Maybe if you used a different mathematical model for determining what your average value is you'd not care about the noise.

Comment: Can you tell me the way to calculate the mean such that I don't have to care about the noise ?